# 2 clicks needed to execute onclick the first time

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, click, display

I'm not really good with javascript...

I have a drop-down menu that show onmouseover or onclick, nd hides onmouseout or with another click.

Here's the whole code i have :

```js
function montrerProduits(wouhou) {
  if (document.getElementById(wouhou).style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(wouhou).style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    document.getElementById(wouhou).style.display = "none"
  }
}

function hideProduits() {
  document.getElementById('wouhou').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li onmouseover="montrerProduits('wouhou')" onmouseout="hideProduits()" onclick="montrerProduits('wouhou')" onfocus="montrerProduits('wouhou')"><a>Créations</a>
  <div id="wouhou" style="display: none">
    *div things*
  </div>
</li>
```

My problem is that after the page is loaded, on my smartphone (i use @media in css, don't know if it has something to do with that) when i click the first time on "Créations", nothing happens. I have to click a second time to show the drop-down menu (#wouhou).
Once i showed it at least once time before, a simple click is enough to show it again...

I spent many time to read other issues about that problem, and understood that the function isn't called before the first click, so the forst click only calls the function, but don't execute the onclick event...

But i have NO IDEA AT ALL about how i can fix my code, so that after the page loads only one click would be enough to show my drop-down menu...

Thank you in advance for all your answers, you will surely save my life (or at least my Sunday) and i'll be eternally grateful !

Comment: The problem is that on mobile, on the first click, both mouseover and onclick are called and they cancel each other.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right !
So what can i do to fix this ?
I think I have to use 2 different functions : one for screen wider than 960px, with which the OnMouseOver will be used to get the drop-down menu visible; and another, for less wider screens, with which only the onClick will be used to show the drop-down menu.
But once again, i've no idea how to do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it doesn't work because whenever you click on the element that's supposed to show your menu (your "li" tag) you actually trigger another of your events which is the "onmouseover" one.

The reason why it might work this way is because smartphones doesn't require their users to "physically" move any device in order to actually move the cursor. So what it does whenever you click on the screen of your phone is that it will first trigger a mouseover event on the element located right at the location you just clicked on; then only it will trigger the onclick event. In your case it means that your function "montrerProduits" will be triggered twice, you won't even have the time to see your menu show up.

I'm not a big user of smartphones and i rarely test my code on them but if i'm not mistaken, your code should work without any problem on a regular computer while using a mouse.

The solution to your issue would be to remove the "onemouseover" event of your "li" element, then it should work properly on smartphones. On the other hand you'll lose the possibility to display your menu everytime the user mouseover the element. If you want to keep both events here's what you could do :

```
var changeDisplay = true; 
function montrerProduits(wouhou) {
   if(changeDisplay) {
     //Prevent new display changes
     changeDisplay = false;
     if (document.getElementById(wouhou).style.display == "none") {
       document.getElementById(wouhou).style.display = "inline";
     } else {
       document.getElementById(wouhou).style.display = "none";
     }
   }
   //Enable display changes to be made again after 0.25 second
   setTimeout(function(){ changeDisplay = true; }, 250);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems logical...

But i really need the possibility to display the drop-down menu with the mouseover event on computers...

Comment: A simple workaround (and perhaps not the only one) to keep using both mouseover and click events would be to add a timeout to your montrerProduits function that would set a variable to true after the display has been changed. Then we'll check  the value of the variable to decide whether or not we can change the display of #wouhou when the function gets called again. I just edited the original answer with some code, check it out.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Tsumagari ! It works !
=D

You're my hero !

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) Also note that the jquery version you are using (1.9.0) is outdated and thus may contain vulnerabilities (it probably does, like many old libraries versions). I advise you to change it to the latest version which is the 3.3.1 one. Je te souhaite bon courage pour la suite du développement de ton site/appli/service.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding your custom script tag earlier and/or using

`<body onload="script();">`

to actually attach the listeners